# Maximum likelihood of coin toss of different type?

Tags: probability, maximum-likelihood, likelihood, expectation-maximization

I was self-studying EM (Expectation Maximization)  algorithm, where I came across this example given by the [paper](http://ai.stanford.edu/~chuongdo/papers/em_tutorial.pdf). In this paper, there are two types of coins A, B with unknown parameters $θ_A$ and $θ_B$. $θ_A$ is: it is probability that it will land on head if coin of type A is chosen.

There are five experiments, each time choosing a type at random and tossing the coin 10 times.

My problem is I can't figure out the exact calculation to determine the maximum likelihood estimation of both biases.
The MLE for $θ_A$ is: $\frac{(number of heads using coin A)}{(total number of flips using coin A)}$

Also in every other examples of MLE I saw some unknown parameters were present in the conditional probability and we try to maximize the likelihood function with respect to that. For example see this example:

If the $X_i$ are independent Bernoulli random variables with unknown parameter $p$, then the probability mass function of each $X_i$ is:
$$
  f(x_i|p)=p^{x_i} (1−p)^{1−x_i}
$$
for $x_i = 0 \text{or 1 and $0 < p < 1$}$. Therefore, the likelihood function $L(p)$ is, by definition:
$$
L(p) =\prod f(x_i;p)  \\
L(p)=p^{∑x_i} (1−p)^{n−∑x_i}
$$
So given the dataset $x_i$ we can maximize this equation w.r.t p.

But what is the parameter of that coin toss example.

Comment: What is your question exactly?  You write "in every other examples of MLE I saw some unknown parameters were present in the conditional probability and we try to maximize the likelihood function with respect to [those parameters]."  Are you asking what the parameter is in coin tossing?

Comment: The parameter in your last example is $p$.

Answer (score 1):

If for each of the five experiments you know which coin is used, A or B, there is no difficulty as, indeed, $\theta_A$ is estimated by the proportion of heads among throws with coin A and the same for $\theta_B$. The problem gets more difficult if the coin is not recorded at each of the five experiments. To quote from the [linked reference](http://ai.stanford.edu/~chuongdo/papers/em_tutorial.pdf) from Nature Biotechnology (2008)

> "Now consider a more challenging variant of the parameter estimation
>   problem in which we are given the recorded head counts x but not the
>   identities z of the coins used for each set of tosses. We refer to z
>   as hidden variables or latent factors."

In this case, the number of heads of ten coins is either a ${\cal B}(10,\theta_A)$ binomial with probability $1/2$ or a ${\cal B}(10,\theta_B)$ binomial with probability $1/2$. This means that, if $x_1,\ldots,x_5$ are the five results, the associated likelihood is
$$\prod_{i=1}^5\left\{ \frac{1}{2}{10 \choose x_i}\theta_A^{x_i}(1-\theta_A)^{10-x_i}+\frac{1}{2}{10 \choose x_i}\theta_B^{x_i}(1-\theta_B)^{10-x_i}\right\}$$which is proportional to
$$\prod_{i=1}^5\left\{\theta_A^{x_i}(1-\theta_A)^{10-x_i}+\theta_B^{x_i}(1-\theta_B)^{10-x_i}\right\}$$and a nuisance to maximise directly.

A resolution by [the EM algorithm](http://ai.stanford.edu/~chuongdo/papers/em_tutorial.pdf) consists in starting from a guess for $(\theta_A,\theta_B)$, e.g., $(\theta_A,\theta_B)=(0.6,0.5)$ and allocating each of the five experiments to one of the two coins, with probabilities (E-step)$$p_A^i=\theta_A^{x_i}(1-\theta_A)^{10-x_i}\Big/\left\{\theta_A^{x_i}(1-\theta_A)^{10-x_i}+\theta_B^{x_i}(1-\theta_B)^{10-x_i}\right\}$$and$$p_B^i=\theta_B^{x_i}(1-\theta_B)^{10-x_i}\Big/\left\{\theta_A^{x_i}(1-\theta_A)^{10-x_i}+\theta_B^{x_i}(1-\theta_B)^{10-x_i}\right\}$$leading to the (M-step) update
$$\theta_A^\text{new}=\sum_{i=1}^5p_A^i x_i \Big/ \sum_{i=1}^5p_A^i \{x_i+10-x_i\}=
\sum_{i=1}^5p_A^i x_i \Big/ 10 \sum_{i=1}^5p_A^i$$and$$\theta_B^\text{new}=\sum_{i=1}^5p_B^i x_i \Big/ 10 \sum_{i=1}^5p_B^i$$ for instance $(\theta_A^\text{new},\theta_B^\text{new})=(0.71,0.58)$, to iterate until convergence...

An interesting remark in the tutorial is that EM was..

> "Introduced as early as 1950 by Ceppellini et al. in the context of
>   gene frequency estimation"

much earlier than the Dempster et al. JRSS B paper.